# How to invoke a Windows Scheduled task or a batch file on a server different to the IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I  have a asp.net web site, I would like a page on that site to be able to invoke a Windows Scheduled task or a batch file on a server different to the IIS server?

Is it possible? 
How should I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to place a Web Service on the server that needs to run the scheduled task/batch file (we'll call this SERVER1). That service should have a method that will invoke the scheduled task/batch file (we'll call this method Invoke).

Then from the asp.net web site on the other server (SERVER2), we'll add a link to run our method on SERVER1, http://SERVER1/YourWebService.asmx/Invoke.

To me this would be the easiest way to manipulate SERVER1 from an outside entity (In your case an asp.net web site).

*Note: You may run into security issues with your Web Service invoking scheduled tasks and running batch files. I believe it can be done, but you may need to play with your .Net permission settings.*

Comment: Why can't you? Add your restrictions to your question and perhaps we can get around them (as long as it's for a legit purpose and not some shady business). :)

Answer (score 1):

Try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).  It's a free tool from Microsoft that will let you execute processes remotely.

Make sure to check out all the other tools in the Sysinternals Suite; there's some really good stuff in there.